# IllegalArgumentException when passing in a class which implements an interface in java reflect

Tags: java, class, reflection, interface

I have a class called

```
ServiceImpl
```

which implents the interface

```
Service
```

I have a method in another jar which I want to call but it takes

```
Service
```

as input. Here is the method:

```
 public void setService(Service service) {
    context.setService(service);
}
```

I tried to use reflection to call this method

```
final ServiceImpl myService = new ServiceImpl(param1, param2);


method = beanClass.getMethod("setService",Service.class);

method.invoke("setService", myService);
```

However I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

It is saying that it expects a Service class but I am passing in an object of type ServiceImpl. But why should that be a problem, since ServiceImpl has implemented Service? How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the `Service` parameter that the reflection is complaining about, it is the first parameter. Effectively, your code attempts to do this:

```
"setService".setService(myService);
```

which does not work for obvious reasons.

Pass the object on which you want to set the service as the first parameter to fix this problem:

```
method.invoke(instanceOfBeanClass, myService);
```

Comment: I should have thought to show the effective call like that, nice one.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to call `setService` on a string object, `"setService"`. [`Method#invoke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-)'s first parameter is the object to call the method on, not the name of the method (it already knows who it is).

You wanted:

```
method.invoke(bean, myService);
```

...where `bean` is an instance of the class whose `Class` object `beanClass` refers to.